# select with group by query and order by query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

hi i have one database and i use this query for get latest records using group by and and order by 
i have use this code for get all record

```
SELECT id,time FROM eventlog WHERE event = '2' ORDER BY `eventlog`.`id` DESC
```

and i get this output:

[image: sql data]

i want to get latest time of every group 
i have use this query for group by with order by query

```
SELECT id,time FROM eventlog WHERE event = '2' GROUP BY id ORDER BY time DESC
```

Comment: you can simply use `max(time)` in your select query..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,MAX(`time`) as `time` FROM eventlog WHERE event = '2' GROUP BY id DESC
```